# Is there an opposite of remove function on JS?

Tags: javascript

I know that on JS exists a remove() function:

```
HTMLElement.remove();
```

I'm just interested to know, if there is a function that does the opposite of remove().

Comment: which *`remove`* do you mean?

Comment: and what this opposite should do? for add to the dom you need to specify where you want to add it. for this you have function like `appendChild()`, to the parent node

Comment: That's not a JavaScript function, it's part of the DOM API.

Comment: The opposite is `appendChild()`.

Comment: There's not exact opposite action, since an element can't insert itself to the DOM. You've to use an insertion method of the exisiting DOM element, like `append`, `appendChild` or `insertBefore` to re-insert a removed element (also you've to keep a reference to the removed element in a JS variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I learned add() function in one of the online tutorials. This worked totally OK on my codes. 
Example:

```
 const closeModal = function() {
    modal.classList.add('hidden');
}

const openModal = function() {
    modal.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```